# C++ Is it possible to override implementation (reimplement) method of a class without inheriting from it?

Tags: c++

Let's say that we have a class definition and implementation:

```cpp
//foo.h
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

class Foo {
public:
    void print();
};

#endif
```

```cpp
//foo.cpp
#include "foo.h"
#include <iostream>

void Foo::print() {
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
}
```

And let's say that those are part of the source code of another project, then I want to override the `Foo::print` behaviour without modifying the original source code, in another .cpp file:

```cpp
//mylib/foo.cpp
#include "../foo.h"
#include <iostream>

void Foo::print() {
    std::cout << "Method overrided!" << std::endl;
}
```

This isn't the regular override pattern (which exists on inherited classes that overrides virtual functions), this would be like a new implementation of the already implemented method.

I don't know if such concept exists in C++, but if it exists, what would be the correct syntax?

Comment: no, you cannot do that.

Comment: You can if you only link to the new object, and not the old one.

Comment: Do you have the source code of the other project? If so, just change it.

Answer (score 1):

If the class resides in a shared library, you can use `LD_PRELOAD` to replace individual functions with new definitions. Described for example here: https://axcheron.github.io/playing-with-ld_preload/

Comment: This is not a C++ solution; it's specific to some unspecified operating system.

Comment: @PeteBecker We live in a society …